# add preauth questions to kerberos responder context

Tags: c, kerberos

I want to use `"pkinit"` preauth question to authenticate with `kerberos`.

But I'm unable to answer `"pkinit"` question because it's not available in the list of questions returned by `krb5_responder_list_questions()`. Only `"password"` is proposed.

How can I add `"pkinit"` or even `"otp"` in the list of preauth questions ?

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded at the end. The problem was that a previous PKCS11 session was not closed before the PKINIT process tried to open a new one.

```
103: C_Initialize
2017-01-12 17:46:43.597
[in] pInitArgs = (nil)
Returned:  401 CKR_CRYPTOKI_ALREADY_INITIALIZED
C_Initialize: cryptoki already initialized
can't open pkcs11 session

104: C_Finalize
2017-01-12 17:46:43.598
Returned:  0 CKR_OK
pkinit_client_prep_questions: no questions to ask
pkinit_client_prep_questions returning 0
pkinit_client_prep_questions: no questions to ask
pkinit_client_prep_questions returning 0

questions_to_answer=password
pkinit_client_process 0x7fffe409f1f0 0x7fffe409f7b0 0x7fffe40a1e70 0x7fffe40a1c20
processing KRB5_PADATA_PK_AS_REQ
pkinit_client_profile 0x7fffe409f1f0 0x7fffe409f7b0 0x7fffe40a1e70 0x7fffe40a2538
pkinit_identity_prompt: 0x7fffe409f1f0 0x7fffe40a23f0 0x7fffe40a2290
```

If all the previous opened sessions are well closed and the KDC is configured to ask the client for a PKINIT preauthentication, we should get the following result :

```
111: C_CloseSession
2017-01-12 18:05:04.655
[in] hSession = 0xbabfcb7f
Returned:  0 CKR_OK

112: C_Finalize
2017-01-12 18:05:04.655
Returned:  0 CKR_OK
pkinit_client_prep_questions: asking question '{"PKCS11:module_name=/usr/local/lib/pkcs11-spy.so:slotid=1:token=CCC":0}'
pkinit_client_prep_questions returning 0
pkinit_client_prep_questions: asking question '{"PKCS11:module_name=/usr/local/lib/pkcs11-spy.so:slotid=1:token=CCC":0}'
pkinit_client_prep_questions returning 0

questions_to_answer=pkinit
pkinit_client_process 0x7fffe4096090 0x7fffe4066cc0 0x7fffe4089760 0x7fffe40897f0
processing KRB5_PADATA_PK_AS_REQ
pkinit_client_profile 0x7fffe4096090 0x7fffe4066cc0 0x7fffe4089760 0x7fffe4089f38
pkinit_identity_prompt: 0x7fffe4096090 0x7fffe4089df0 0x7fffe4089c70
```